# Why does this circuit not activate my solenoid?

Tags: arduino, solenoid

I'm trying to control a solenoid from an Arduino, using a transistor as switch.

Here's the schematic I'm trying to achieve and the actual physical circuit but when D9 is HIGH, the voltage between solenoid terminals is zero.

[image: schematic]

[image: physical circuit]

Soldering seems fine after checking for continuity, so the problem seems to be on the circuit design or implementation.

For reference: the solenoid is 12V DC 300mA rated and the PSU is 12V 2A rated.

Comment: Your base resistor night be too high. The gain at Ice=50mA is only 30 and you wan ten times that. Can this BJT even handle 300mA?

Comment: @Lowb Please use the post editor to embed the images in your question instead of linking to them.

Comment: OK, embedded the pics.
@DKNguyen, as per the datasheet I've been reviewing, it can handle 600mA...

Comment: Did you connect Arduino GND as well?

Comment: Yes, GND comes from Arduino pins.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at a [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/68/2n5550_2n5551-1510795.pdf) for the 2N5551 shows that at the 300 mA your solenoid coil is rated at the \$h_{FE}\$ is under 20.

Figuring base current using \$h_{FE}=20\$ we have $$\frac{300mA}{20} = 15 mA$$
or worse.

15 mA will drop 15 V across the 1k resistor, so unless you're Arduino is outputting over 15 V you're probably not going to get enough drive.

Also verify the make of transistor, some [datasheets](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/2N5550_5551.pdf) show DC collector current rated at 300mA. The 2N5551 is a high voltage transistor, not really meant to drive a solenoid, you should probably look for a more suitable transistor.

You can lower the resistance to a value that will allow enough base current dependent on the drive voltage. You also have to make sure the Arduino outputs enough current.

Comment: It'd be great if you could point me to that info on the datasheet so I can understand why and what and where. Thanks.

Comment: @Lowb In the first link, under "TYPICAL ELECTRICAL CHARACTERISTICS" the first graph is DC current gain vs. collector current.